# Intellij typing character combinations like :=

Tags: intellij-idea, goland

When programming in Go, I tend to use assignment statement using the operator `:=` often.
But I find it difficult to type these two characters `:=`. Is there any short cut or a autocomplete way to type `:=` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GoLand or IntelliJ IDEA with Go plugin has a handy shortcut to declare a new variable:

- Type `:` where do you want to define a variable.
- Press `Tab` to apply [Live Template](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/go/using-live-templates.html).

[image: A short video on how to apply a live template]

You can configure an abbreviation or expand shortcut via *Preferences/Settings | Editor | Live Templates | Go | Variable declaration*.